# Web API using Core and .Net framework 4.5.2. CAnnot set connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have an application that includes a Web API Core startup project.
I found that I cannot scaffold an existing database in .Net Core for a View.
So I decided for my Web API Core application that I will have to use the .Net framework and get the data in a project using EF6.
However in the startup project (Web API Core) I need to set the connection string. For this I need EF6, and it would seem that I cannot do this even if I add EF6 in the project (maybe this can't be done in a Core project?).
So this code fails where I attempt to add the context;

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddMvcOptions(o => o.OutputFormatters.Add(
                new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter()));
        var connectionString = Startup.Configuration["connectionStrings:propertiesConnectionString"];
        services.AddDbContext<SurveyEntities>(o => o.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        services.AddScoped<IPropertiesRepo, PropertiesRepo>();

    }
```

If I download EF6, I get this error;

> Error CS0311  The type 'Properties.EF6.MSurveyV2Entities' cannot be
>   used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method
>   'EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext(IServiceCollection,
>   Action, ServiceLifetime)'. There is no
>   implicit reference conversion from 'Properties.EF6.MSurveyV2Entities'
>   to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'.

So how do I fix this?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error CS0311 The type 'Properties.EF6.MSurveyV2Entities' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext<TContext>(IServiceCollection, Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder>, ServiceLifetime)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Properties.EF6.MSurveyV2Entities' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'.

Comment: It would seem that a Core API cannot set a connection string for a EF6 project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in this link here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6
If the link breaks this is a summary;
In the EF6 project I put in a partial class for the db context where a constructor takes the connection string as a parameter
public partial class SurveyEntities

```
{
    public SurveyEntities(string connString) : base(connString)
    {
    }
}
```

In the Web.API core project I have in the startup;

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvcCore();
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("SurveyEntities");
        services.AddScoped<SurveyEntities>(_ => new SurveyEntities(connectionString));
        services.AddScoped<IPropertiesRepo, PropertiesRepo>();

    }
```

and in the controller I have

```
   public class ContractController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IPropertiesRepo PropertiesRepo;
        private readonly SurveyEntities db;
        public ContractController(SurveyEntities _db,IPropertiesRepo repo)
        {
            this.db = _db;
            this.PropertiesRepo = repo;
        }

        [HttpGet("getall")]
        public IActionResult GetContracts()
        {
            var contracts = this.PropertiesRepo.GetAllLiveContracts().ToList();
            return Ok(contracts);
        }
    }
```

The call to the api now works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the connection string stored in appsetings.json. This is the way you have the most flexiblity configuring ASP.NET Core.

i.e.

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
      "MyDatabase": "Server (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.ConsoleApp.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
   },
}
```

After that in configure services

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>    
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase")));
}
```

You have more info and examples here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings